# Rationale behind Python's preferred for syntax

Tags: python, performance

What is the rationale behind the advocated use of the `for i in xrange(...)`-style looping constructs in Python? For simple integer looping, the difference in overheads is substantial. I conducted a simple test using two pieces of code:

File `idiomatic.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

M = 10000
N = 10000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x, y = 0, 0
    for x in xrange(N):
        for y in xrange(M):
            pass
```

File `cstyle.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

M = 10000
N = 10000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x, y = 0, 0
    while x < N:
        while y < M:
            y += 1
        x += 1
```

Profiling results were as follows:

```
bash-3.1$ time python cstyle.py

real    0m0.109s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s

bash-3.1$ time python idiomatic.py

real    0m4.492s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.031s
```

I can understand why the Pythonic version is slower -- I imagine it has a lot to do with calling xrange N times, perhaps this could be eliminated if there was a way to rewind a generator. However, with this deal of difference in execution time, why would one prefer to use the Pythonic version?

**Edit:** I conducted the tests again using the code Mr. Martelli provided, and the results were indeed better now:

I thought I'd enumerate the conclusions from the thread here:

1) *Lots of code at the module scope is a bad idea,* even if the code is enclosed in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

2) *Curiously enough, modifying the code that belonged to `thebadone` to my incorrect version (letting y grow without resetting) produced little difference in performance, even for larger values of M and N.

Comment: Your timing is flawed, I think. Run multiple trials, and perhaps have some computation actually performed inside it to get rid of any possible optimization out of the loop

Comment: +1 Very interesting question. After reading Martinelli's answer, this question is yet more interesting to me, because it shows the subtle differences between invoking a piece of code inside and outside a function.

Comment: -1: Since the basis for the question was fundamentally incorrect code, would you please close the question.

Comment: One rationale is that you're more likely to create correct code using the pythonic way. Which you've proved :)

Comment: When you see `real` time that's inconsistent with `user` time + `sys` time, it usually means your benchmark is flawed, and something else was consuming machine resources while you tried to run your code.

Comment: I think you are mistaken in claiming that "while" loops are idiomatic in C... C and C++ both have for-loops as well (although not the same kind as Python), and I was always taught to prefer for-loops (not just in Python but also in C and C++), because the initialization and termination conditions are stated upfront, and so it is less error-prone than the while-loop equivalent (which you have aptly demonstrated).

Comment: Oh, no no, I merely named it C-style because such loops are seen frequently in C. I'd personally use a for loop for iteration over numbers, and a lot else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's the proper comparison, e.g. in loop.py:

```
M = 10000
N = 10000

def thegoodone():
   for x in xrange(N):
       for y in xrange(M):
           pass

def thebadone():
    x = 0
    while x < N:
        y = 0
        while y < M:
            y += 1
        x += 1
```

All substantial code should **always** be in functions -- putting a hundred million loops at a module's top level shows reckless disregard for performance and makes a mockery of any attempts at *measuring* said performance.

Once you've done that, you see:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import loop' 'loop.thegoodone()'
10 loops, best of 3: 3.45 sec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import loop' 'loop.thebadone()'
10 loops, best of 3: 10.6 sec per loop
```

So, properly measured, the bad way that you advocate is about 3 times slower than the good way which Python promotes.  I hope this makes you reconsider your erroneous advocacy.

Comment: "All substantial code should always be in functions - putting a hundred million loops at a module's top level shows reckless disregard for performance" (I see.) Could you explain why?

Comment: @Federico, **speed**.  Variable get and set is highly optimized in functions, but can't possibly be at module top-level.  E.g., assuming that my laptop and Glenn's machine are equivalent, from our numbers you see a factor of 2 difference for doing things the proper way (all substantial code in functions) vs the totally wrong way (substantial code at module top level).  Benchmark it yourself!-)

Comment: I just did. At module level: 14.3s vs. 36.0s. Local to function: 8.6s vs. 18.5s. (!!) I didn't know, thank you.

Comment: +1 I can't blame susmits, after all who whould know that code inside functions would run that different compared as running outside of a function. Reading your answer makes completely sense, because after all, code "floating around" the file is module code and this is not evident when someone is new to the language ( as my self ). Sometimes is easy to think about python as a supercharged bash :-S which, obviously as shown here, it is not. :)

Comment: I've repeated the test. The idiomatic for loop is 5 times faster than the while loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611867/rationale-behind-pythons-preferred-for-syntax/2612089#2612089

Comment: +1 @Alex, Could you expand a little more on why get and set can't be optimized at module top level, and why they can be inside functions?

Comment: @007brendan, module-level variables are visible from outside the module (i.e., other modules), so every single little change applied to them _must_ be immediately applied, every fetch _must_ be done afresh from the module's dict, unless you can **prove** otherwise with 100% certainty... which, given threading, is just impossible. Function-local variables are **not** visible (much less alterable) outside that function instance, which empowers all kinds of optimizations in any semi-decent Python implementation.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had no idea that declaring variables in module scope could have such an impact on performance, 3x seems way more reasonable in comparison.

Comment: Also, in case it wasn't 100% clear, module-level variables must be looked up and set via a hash table (the_module.__dict__) while function-local variables are looked up and set in an array local to that function call.

Answer (score 11):

You forgot to reset y to 0 after the inner loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
M = 10000
N = 10000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x, y = 0, 0
    while x < N:
        while y < M:
            y += 1
        x += 1
        y = 0
```

ed: 20.63s after fix vs. 6.97s using xrange

Comment: I was about to answer similarly. My corrected while-loop code ran about 3 times slower than the for-loop code.

Comment: In all seriousness, no.  Language idioms always have to take reasonable performance into account; if the xrange idiom really *was* 40 times slower, it would be a flawed idiom that should either be fixed or no longer used.  Readability is important, very often even at the expense of some performance--but not that much.

Comment: Besides the performance, this error in the question is an excellent demonstration why high level loops are preferred!

Answer (score 3):

**good for iterating over data structures**

The `for i in ...` syntax is great for iterating over data structures.  In a lower-level language, you would generally be iterating over an array indexed by an int, but with the python syntax you can eliminate the indexing step.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a direct answer to the question, but i want to open the dialog a bit more on `xrange()`. two things:

A. there is something wrong with one of the OP statements that no one has corrected yet (yes, in addition to the bug in the code of not resetting `y`):

"I imagine it has a lot to do with calling xrange N times...."

unlike traditional counting **`for`** loops, Python's is more like a shell's **`foreach`**... looping over an iterable. therefore, `xrange()` is called *exactly once*, not "N times."

B. `xrange()` is the name of this function in Python 2. it replaces and is renamed to `range()` in Python 3, so keep this in mind when porting. if you didn't know already, `xrange()` returns an iterator(-like object) while `range()` returns lists. since the latter is more inefficient, it has been deprecated in favor of `xrange()` which is more memory-friendly. the workaround in Python 3, for all those who *need* to have a list is `list(range(N))`.

Comment: I thought that each time the inner loop finished all its iterations, an xrange(M) object was defined again, because AFAIK, generators could not be rewound.

Answer (score 0):

I've repeated the test from [@Alex Martelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611867/rationale-behind-pythons-preferred-for-syntax/2611917#2611917). The idiomatic for loop is *5* times faster than the while loop:

```
python -mtimeit -s'from while_vs_for import while_loop as loop' 'loop(10000)'
10 loops, best of 3: 9.6 sec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'from while_vs_for import for_loop as loop'   'loop(10000)'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.83 sec per loop
```

**while_vs_for.py**:

```
def while_loop(N):
    x = 0
    while x < N:
        y = 0
        while y < N:
            pass
            y += 1
        x += 1

def for_loop(N):
    for x in xrange(N):
        for y in xrange(N):
            pass
```

At module level:

```
$ time -p python for.py
real 4.38
user 4.37
sys 0.01
$ time -p python while.py
real 14.28
user 14.28
sys 0.01
```